# Does anyone know how to integrate sagepay inFrame payments?

Tags: php, opayo

i need to integrate sagepay using their 'inFrame' method (basically just their payment form in an iframe i'm told). Their site is abysmal though and does not tell you how to do it. I'm presuming I just need a url for the src attribute of my iframe that maybe i stick some get variables on the end of or something like that? They neglect to mention anywhere how to do it though!

Thanks

Comment: their site does suck but their telephone support is not too shabby from what i remember (i have set up sage pay with forms several times). they wont tell you how to do it but they got me to the files i needed to get the job done - a pdf telling you everything in good detail

Comment: you will need to crate an account though i think to get anywhere at all and i think their guides are in the log in area of the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just created an account and had a two second scan of their site. It appears to be a type of what they call "server" integration (as opposed to form based).

This means you will need to create a secure connection between your server and their services to handle the transactions. So a bit more than setting a src attribute with some params ;-)

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document

Comment: They may have all the code you need done for you, I know they have classic asp and aspx solutions that are pretty much ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

On version 2.23 you use "server" integration and set the iframe src to the "NextURL" returned by sagepay after you have sent the payment information request. Ensure your set "PROFILE" to "LOW" as this will strip out all buttons and cause the success/failure URL to return to the iframes parent window (ie the page on your server).